# Bottom Tab Navigator not showing on home screen (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to asking about why bottom tab didnt showing at home screen (hidden)
here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Signup from './screens/signup';
import Login from './screens/login';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Loading from './screens/Loading';
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import ForgotPassword from './screens/ForgotPassword';
import ApplyLoan from './screens/ApplyLoan';
import Profile from './screens/Profile';
import LoanHistory from './screens/LoanHistory';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';




export default class App extends React.Component  {
render()
{
return (
<AppContainer>
<RootNavigator/>
<MainTab/>
</AppContainer>
);
}
}


const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
loading: {
screen: Loading,
navigationOptions: {
  headerShown: false,
  headerTransparent: true,
  },
  },
```

Welcome: {
screen: Welcome,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
signup: {
screen: Signup,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
login: {
screen: Login,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
Home: {
screen: Home,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
ForgotPassword: {
screen: ForgotPassword,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
ApplyLoan: {
screen: ApplyLoan,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
LoanHistory: {
screen: LoanHistory,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
Profile: {
screen: Profile,
navigationOptions: {
headerShown: false,
headerTransparent: true,
},
},
InitialRouteName : Loading
});

const MainTab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
{

```
  Home: { screen: Home,  
      navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Home',  
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
              <View>  
                  <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-home'}/>  
              </View>),  
      }  
  },  
  Profile: { screen: Profile,  
      navigationOptions:{  
          tabBarLabel:'Profile',  
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (  
              <View>  
                  <Icon style={[{color: tintColor}]} size={25} name={'ios-person'}/>  
              </View>),  
          activeColor: '#f60c0d',  
          inactiveColor: '#f65a22',  
          barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#f69b31' },  
      }  
  },
```

},
{
initialRouteName: "Home",
activeColor: '#f0edf6',
inactiveColor: '#226557',
barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#3BAD87' },
},
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator, MainTab);

Is something wrong about my code?

Comment: What about others screens? Do they working as expected? Can you tell me your react navigation version?

Comment: my react navigation version is 4.4.1

Comment: stack navigator is working. Only bottom tab navigator not working at all. I want to showing at home screen actually (or dashboard)

Comment: I think you should update your navigation version to latest i.e. v-5

Comment: still not showing about although i already separate bottom tab

Comment: are you able to navigate to other screens like "Profile"?

Comment: its working now